# Entity CRUD operations - Edit (update) issues

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, crud

I'm tryin to learn few things about Zend Framework and I got stucked on so simple operation like 'Edit' DB entry.

I've got list of contacts in MySQL db and my intention is to fill form with information from one row, edit it and save it back to db (update statement). I tried almost everthing that came into my mind, checked out google and book about ZF, but there is some problem all the time. At this moment, when I want to do update, zf and mysql will create new db entry with new id and edited information filled in, but that is not what i want to do obviously because instead of one updated entry in DB I've got two - old one and new one with updated information.

Here are the importat parts of my code...please have a look at it, I can't figure out what I'm missing here.

part of indexcontroller:

```
public function createcontactAction()
{
    $createContactForm = $this->_helper->_formLoader('addContact');
    $this->view->addContactForm = $createContactForm;
}

public function editcontactAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $contactModel = new Application_Model_Contacts();
    $contactRow = $contactModel->find($id)->current();

    $addContactForm = $this->_helper->formLoader('addContact');

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('send', false) !== false) {
        if ($addContactForm->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {

            $contactRow->setFromArray($addContactForm->getValues());

            $contactRow->save();

            $this->_redirect('/index/editcontact/id/' . $contactRow->id);
        }
    } else {
        $addContactForm->populate($contactRow->toArray());
    }

    $this->view->addContactForm = $addContactForm;
}

public function savecontactAction()
{
    $form = $this->_helper->formLoader('addContact');

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('send', false) !== false) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
            $contactModel = new Application_Model_Contacts();
            $contactRow = $contactModel->createRow($form->getValues());
            $contactRow->save();

            $this->_redirect('/index/editcontact/id/' . $contactRow->id);
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

form - parts that matters:

class Application_Form_AddContact extends Zend_Form
{

```
public function init()
{


    $this->setAction('/index/savecontact');
    $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);
    $this->setAttrib('id', 'index_savecontact');

    $contactFirstName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('first_name', array('size'=>32, 'maxlength'=>64, 'label'=>'Křestní', 'required'=>false));
    $contactLastName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('last_name', array('size'=>32, 'maxlength'=>64, 'label'=>'Přímění', 'required'=>true));

.
.
.

    $contactNotes = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('notes', array('cols'=>32, 'rows'=>1, 'label'=>'Poznámky', 'required'=>false));

    $contactSend = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('send', array('label'=>'Odeslat'));

    $this->addElements(array ($contactFirstName, $contactLastName, $contactStreet, $contactHouseNumber, $contactCity, $contactZipCode, $contactCountry,
            $contactPhoneNumber, $contactMobileNumber, $contactEmail, $contactWebPage, $contactCrn, $contactVat, $contactNotes, $contactSend));
```

Thank you very much!

(If theres anything more you could need to help me with this just ask for it)

EDIT:

heres model for contacts:

```
class Application_Model_Contacts extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name    = 'contacts';
    protected $_primary = 'id';

}
```

Comment: Post some of your Model code, that makes a big difference on how you code the controller.

Comment: edit: added model to question

Comment: thanks all for help, issue solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty with regards to `Zend_Db_Table` and `Zend_Db_Table_Row` (I'm assuming that is what your model uses), but my bet would be that you are missing the Primary Key (PK) in your `$contactRow` - I'm guessing you probably don't supply it via the form as I see you get it through `GET`. So just set the `id` to `$id` in your `$contactRow` and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks, this helped...but (my bad) there was also need to call editcontact action from form submit, not save.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an update without providing the id of the row you want to update. The data used for the query is `$form->getValues()` but the form doesn't seem to contain the id of the contact. Add the id as a hidden field (with the id as the value) to your form or set it separately with `$contactRow->id = $id` and it should update instead of insert.

Comment: i tried to add id to form as hidden element and in controller set $contactRow->id = $id, but sql generates error:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '11' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

In `editcontactAction()`, before `$contactRow->save();`, add : `$contactRow->id = $id`.
 If your row doesn't have a id specified, `save()` can't update.